# Проверка пересечения изображения с криволинейной областью

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

Суть задачи.  Будет магазин одежды, в котором на майки можно будет наносить изображения. http://skrinshoter.ru/s/231017/nzmW4z77

Т.е. загружаем фото и его можно двигать, вращать и т.п.  Это понятно.

Но! Задача в том, что изображение можно двигать только в пределах пунктирной красной линии (кривой)... Как это вообще можно реализовать средствами JS?

Comment: т.е. как можно проверить - находится ли изображение внутри этой области или пересекло границу?

Comment: Можно сделать что бы скрыть часть изображения, если оно выходит за пределы красной линии.

Comment: сделать на верхнем слое PNG с дыркой? )

Comment: ну можно так, можно сделать с помощью svg

Answer (score 0):

Использовать одну из библиотек для работы с canvas (я так понимаю, что без canvas тут все равно не обойдется), в которой есть проверка пересечений точек. Например, [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org/examples/path-intersections/)

Comment: Интересно ) спасибо )